# How to remove this codes/keys from lines?

Tags: notepad++, text-editors, sublime-text-3, text-editing, notepad

Hello everyone i hope you all have a good day.

I want to know how to remove/delete the following codes/keys from lines.

**Example List:**

```
m-1407-m-00
64582e-2bd9-4b06-a9a1-78bfd42a7e6d
SimpleHere123
586273ed-c062-47e6-a70f-ff91ad7c4d57666
1456Number20Tester
B2R8-X8NC-GPCP-N7AA-B6KM
Testing23Simple
G68T-XNPG-W1M2-6JEM-GNXF
N0rmalT3sTin6g
le-pj-du-81
6ba509ba-c69a-487b-9
ale-91-07-15
```

**Remove/Delete Target:**

```
64582e-2bd9-4b06-a9a1-78bfd42a7e6d
586273ed-c062-47e6-a70f-ff91ad7c4d57666
B2R8-X8NC-GPCP-N7AA-B6KM
G68T-XNPG-W1M2-6JEM-GNXF
6ba509ba-c69a-487b-9
```

**Result Needed:**

```
m-1407-m-00
SimpleHere123
1456Number20Tester
Testing23Simple
N0rmalT3sTin6g
le-pj-du-81
ale-91-07-15
```

Thank you in advance for your help & answer, much appreciated <3.

Comment: What are the rules to delete some lines and not the other ones?

Comment: it is their mixed letters & numbers OR numbers & letters after each separator -

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex does the job:

```
^(?:\w+|(?:[a-z]+|\d+)(?:-(?:[a-z]+|\d+))*)$
```

[Demo & explanation](https://regex101.com/r/D243RL/1)

Comment: Thank you so much @Toto it works <3.

Comment: Another quick question please because i tried many things for it but none won't work, in this emails:

example1@t-online.de:
example2@t/online.de:

how i remove anything after the @ that not a Letters or Numbers OR - OR _ OR .

i tried [^a-z0-9@.-_:]+ what i am doing wrong?

Comment: @DeathRival: It's a different question, I can't answer in comments. You should ask a new one.